# Whats wrong with levelBaseStart?

Tags: c#, operators, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerStats : MonoBehaviour {
[System.Serializable]
public class BaseStats {

    string name;
    int currentLevel;
    int targetLevel = currentLevel + 1;
    int currentHp;
    int maxHp;
    int currentAp;
    int maxAp;

    int strength;
    int toughness;
    int agility;
    int intelligence;
    int willPower;
    int luck;

    int attack;
    int hitPercentage;
    int defence;
    int defPercentage;
    int powerAttack;
    int powerDefence;
    int powerDefPercentage;

    int totalExp;
    int totalExpNeeded;
    int expTilLevel;
    int expMod;
    int expBase;
    int levelBaseStart = [(targetLevel- 2 ) / 10] * 10 + 2;

}

void AddExp(int experience){


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

I thought [ ] took the number and made it a whole number, if thats not the case how would I do that? I'm making the exp variables to use in my equation to calculate the total exp needed to reach a certain level.Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: Math.Floor or Math.Ceiling? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx

Comment: use Math.Ceiling(value) or Math.Floor(value) as your need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of [] being used for making a number a whole number...

You could use `Math.Floor((targetLevel- 2 ) / 10)` to achieve a whole number
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx

Comment: Im going to finish writing this bit then repost it with the errors, Math.Floor is what I need though ThankS!!